# how to print data stored in multidimensional array and fetched from database using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

i'm trying to build a news website using PHP and MYSQL so i am storing the news and stories in a database and i'm trying to print the categories of the stored news and the $result of the query when i try to fetch the categories from a database is

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["category"]=> string(5) "Music" 
            ["parent"]=> string(1) "1" 
            } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
            ["id"]=> string(1) "2" 
            ["category"]=> string(7) "Fashion"
            ["parent"]=> string(1) "1" 
            } 
}
```

I've  tried to use a foreach loop as shown in the code below
using that sql query

```
"SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 1";
```

and the main php code is

```
echo "<h1>Topics</h1>";
      
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 1";
$result = $db -> getRows($sql,[]);
$numrows = $db -> getrows("SELECT count(*) FROM stories",[]);
if($numrows == 0) {
    echo "<p>No categories</p>";
} else {
    foreach($result as $row["category"]=>$cat){
        echo implode('-', $cat) . "\n";
    }
}
```

i want to have thous results

> *fashion
>
> *Music

what i'm doing wrong and what should i change in my code to make it work ?

Comment: so what are u getting now? why are u using `implode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach loop can be made a little simpler and produce what you want

```
echo "<h1>Topics</h1>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent = 1";
$result = $db -> getRows($sql,[]);
$numrows = $db -> getrows("SELECT count(*) FROM stories",[]);
if($numrows == 0) {
    echo "<p>No categories</p>";
} else {
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo $row['category'] . "\n";
    }
}
```